# What is the purpose of standardization in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, normalization

I'm just getting started with learning about K-nearest neighbor and am having a hard time understanding why standardization is required. Reading through, I came across a section saying

> When independent variables in training data are measured in different
>   units, it is important to standardize variables before calculating
>   distance. For example, if one variable is based on height in cms, and
>   the other is based on weight in kgs then height will influence more on
>   the distance calculation.

Since K nearest neighbor is just a comparison of distances apart, why does it matter if one of the variables has values of a larger range since it is what it is.

Considering 3 points A,B & C with x,y co-ordinates (x in cm, y in grams) A(2,2000), B(8,9000) and C(10,20000), the ranking of the points as distance from origin for example (or any other point), will be the same whether the y values are in grams,pounds, tonnes or any other combinations of units for both x and y so where's the need to standardise. Every example or QA i see brushes through with the same statement of 'one variable influencing the other' without a real example of how this might occur. Again, how does one know when this influence is too much as to call for standardization.

Also,what exactly does standardization do to the values? One of the formulas does it by Xs = (X-mean)/(max-min) Where does such a formula come from and what is it really doing? Hopefully someone can offer me a simplified explanation or give me a link to a site or book that explains this in simple terms for beginners.

Comment: @sAguinaga Thanks  that answers my last point. Im quite confused by the need to do it in the first place.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287425/why-do-you-need-to-scale-data-in-knn See this stack exchange question that shows the point quite well

Comment: A better answer is offered [here](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/z-score/) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/when-to-standardize-your-data-in-4-minutes-f9282190707e) z score lets you do standardization: z = x –  x̄  / s, where x̄ (the sample mean)  and s (the sample standard deviation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Considering 3 points A,B & C with x,y co-ordinates (x in cm, y in
>   grams) A(2,2000), B(8,9000) and C(10,20000), the ranking of the points
>   as distance from origin for example (or any other point), will be the
>   same whether the y values are in grams,pounds, tonnes or any other
>   combinations of units for both x and y so where's the need to
>   standardise.

This is true for the example you provided, but not for euclidean distance between points in general. Look at this example:

```
def euclidian_distance(a, b):
    return ((a[0] - b[0])**2 + (a[1] - b[1])**2)**0.5

a1 = 10   #10 grams
a2 = 10  #10 cm
b1 = 10   #10 gram
b2 = 100  #100 cm
c1 = 100  #100 gram
c2 = 10   #10 cm 

# using (grams, cm) 
A_g_cm = [a1, a2]
B_g_cm = [b1, b2]
C_g_cm = [c1, c2]

print('[g, cm] A-B:', euclidian_distance(A_g_cm, B_g_cm))
print('[g, cm] A-C:', euclidian_distance(A_g_cm, C_g_cm))

# using (kg, cm) 
A_kg_cm = [a1/1000, a2]
B_kg_cm = [b1/1000, b2]
C_kg_cm = [c1/1000, c2]

print('[kg, cm] A-B:', euclidian_distance(A_kg_cm, B_kg_cm))
print('[kg, cm] A-C:', euclidian_distance(A_kg_cm, C_kg_cm))

# using (grams, m) 
A_g_m = [a1, a2/100]
B_g_m = [b1, b2/100]
C_g_m = [c1, c2/100]

print('[g, m] A-B:', euclidian_distance(A_g_m, B_g_m))
print('[g, m] A-C:', euclidian_distance(A_g_m, C_g_m))

# using (kilo, m) 
A_kg_m = [a1/1000, a2/100]
B_kg_m = [b1/1000, b2/100]
C_kg_m = [c1/1000, c2/100]

print('[kg, m] A-B:', euclidian_distance(A_kg_m, B_kg_m))
print('[kg, m] A-C:', euclidian_distance(A_kg_m, C_kg_m))
```

Output:

```
[g, cm] A-B: 90.0
[g, cm] A-C: 90.0
[kg, cm] A-B: 90.0
[kg, cm] A-C: 0.09000000000000001
[g, m] A-B: 0.9
[g, m] A-C: 90.0
[kg, m] A-B: 0.9
[kg, m] A-C: 0.09000000000000001
```

Here you can clearly see that the choice of units influence the ranking, thus the need for standardization.

Comment: Exactly the sort of example I've been looking for! Nice and clear thanks a lot mate.,really struggled for a while with this

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons for the standardization, the relevant reasons for the KNN algorithm important since the algorithm is based on calculating the distance between neighbours. Let's assume that the distance measure that we are using is the euclidian distance and we are having 2 features x in grams and y in kilometres.

If we'll take a look at the distance (d) formula between 2 points (p,q) with 2 features (1,2):
[image]

We may notice, that the term (q1-p1) is in grams and (q2-p2) is in kms. There are several issues with this:

1. we are summing deltas with different units
2. we are summing deltas with different scale
3. we are summing deltas of features with different distribution/variance

For example, the first feature has a small magnitude of delta (between 2 points) which is meaningful in its scale and variance, the second feature has a delta with a large magnitude but in its scale and variance it is negligible (1km while reducing 200k km with 199k km).

We can agree that the points are far in the feature 1 space and are close to each other in the feature 2 space, but, our distance metric might not detect that.

The Standardization of the features before applying the distance metric would solve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Another goog reason is that standarization of features may serve as a way of
*preconditioning* the problem.

Steepest descent optimization algorithms does not work well on ill-conditioned
cases, for instance, when the loss function shows *ravines* and *ridges*. In
such cases, vanilla Gradient Descent may oscillate in the direction of the
largest gradient, *deviating* from the right direction to the optimum point, and
thus, convergence may be very slow. This issue can be addressed with more
sophisticated optimizes (RMSprop, Adam...) but standardization of features
may *precondition* the scenario (smoothing the *ravines* of the loss
function, for example)

Answer (score 0):

> Considering 3 points A,B & C with x,y co-ordinates (x in cm, y in
>   grams) A(2,2000), B(8,9000) and C(10,20000), the ranking of the points
>   as distance from origin for example (or any other point), will be the
>   same whether the y values are in grams,pounds, tonnes or any other
>   combinations of units for both x and y so where's the need to
>   standardise.

I'm not sure this is entirely right:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
df = df.drop('species', axis=1)

ss = StandardScaler()

ed1 = euclidean_distances(df)
ed2 = euclidean_distances(ss.fit_transform(df))

ed1_max = np.array([np.argmax(i) for i in ed1])
ed2_max = np.array([np.argmax(i) for i in ed2])

print(np.where(ed1_max == ed2_max, 1, 0).mean())
```

So for each sample in the iris dataset, this calculates the sample that's furthest away in euclidean distance for both the scaled and unscaled data, and then calculates the percentage of samples where they match. The output is 0.33. So scaling definitely affects the ranking of distances between samples.

So the problem is unscaled data tends to lead to the features with a larger scale drowning out the vote of the other features in determining distance to other samples. Scaling prevents that.